# Can I install Visual Studio 2010 Premium & Ultimate simultaneously & safely on my machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate installed on my 64-bit machine presently. My company is planning to downgrade our license to Premium shortly. I plan to install a trial version of Premium on my machine to check out if we will be missing out on any essential features. My question is will this screw up my existing Ultimate setup, especially after I uninstall the trial version of Premium?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably.

While different versions of Visual Studio (2008, 2010, 2012, Express) etc. will sit happily alongside each other the different editions of the same version won't.

Why don't you install the Premium version on a virtual machine to see if you're missing anything.

Microsoft has a [handy guide](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compare) to the different editions. The difference between Premium and Ultimate are the 6 things at the bottom of the list:

- Reliably capture and reproduce bugs found during manual and exploratory testing to eliminate "no repro" bugs
- Understand the dependencies and relationships in your code through visualization
- Visualize the impact of a change, or a potential change in your code
- Collect and analyze runtime diagnostic data from production systems
- Perform unlimited web performance and load testing
- Design architectural layer diagrams to then validate code implements the architecture

So if you do any of these now, you'll be missing functionality once you downgrade. Now is the time to tell your boss that you need Ultimate. If you don't use any of these features then you won't notice the difference.

Comment: +1  I've messed up my main dev machine too many times (once, that is) by thinking that side-by-side installations of software would work.